# kvm-switch, dual monitor, only share one monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

Setup: 2 physical machines, and 3 LCD monitors,
each machine has its own LCD monitor, and I would like to share the 3rd LCD monitor using KVM-switch. 
Is this possible?

(I have already shared the keyboard and mouse using Synergy.)

Answer (score 3):

I had this setup. It worked great.

For each machine, I had the center, shared monitor be the secondary monitor. The outside monitors were the primary monitor for each system, holding the task bar and menus.

I did not use Synergy. Rather I used the keyboard and mouse attached to the kvm switch. Each machine also had an additional mouse attached, so that I could affect the machine when the kvm switch was pointed at the other machine.